# How to Get Id from class selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<input  id="1" class="Find">
<input  id="2" class="Find">
<input  id="3" class="Find">

$('.Find').autocomplete('auto/data.php?mode='+ $('.Find').attr('id')  +'', {    
                    width: 220,
                    max: 5,
                    selectFirst: false,      
                    mustMatch:true,
                    formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {return  value.split("|")[0];}
                    });
```

In this case the code `$('.Find').attr('id')` only shows the first array. Not showing the specific id where I needed.

I've done to change with new var `n` change this line `$('.Find').attr('id')` with new variable but the result is `undefined`.

The new var look like this `var one = $("#GetObjc").attr("value");`

Can anyone help me. What should I do to get the specific id on that class. Sorry if am make confuse cozz am newbie.

Comment: You have 3 element with class find. How do you know which one to use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you looking for. but you can get all `id`s using [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/).

```
var ids ='';
$(".Find").each(function( index, value ) {
  ids += $(this).attr('id') + ',';
});
```

Then you can split `ids` variable or something like this.

**[Check JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3fskffm3/)**

In your case i think it's useful for you:

```
$('.Find').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.autocomplete('auto/data.php?mode='+ $this.attr('id')  + '', {    
        width: 220,
        mzx: 5,
        selectFirst: false,      
        mustMatch:true,
        formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {return  value.split("|")[0];}
    });
});
```

Comment: give me a clue what should i do ?? vote the answer ? or what ?? cozz am not understand how's the rule ?? please tell me cozz am not undersstand what must i do for the answer...

Comment: forgive me for my ignorance, because I do not know its purpose,now i mark ur answer for the fisrt answer in my question..hope u hope you understand me with my ignorance

Answer (score 1):

2% chance I understood your question in the right way but it seems that you need to iterate through your element list:

```
    $('.Find').each(function() {
        $(this).autocomplete('auto/data.php?mode='+ $(this).attr('id')  +'', {
            width: 220,
            max: 5,
            selectFirst: false,      
            mustMatch:true,
            formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {return  value.split("|")[0];}
        });
    });
```

Comment: U are the master...thanks a  lot ...working verry good...am trying for all the time and u just one minnut and donee ....great great

Comment: No no no. You just have to know more how jQuery works.
When you do $(".Find").autocomplete, it targets many elements: all your input elements with the "Find" class.
But when you call $('.Find').attr('id'), it will always retrieve the id of the first matched element (the one with id "1"), so your autocomplete does not work.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to do this :

```
$('.Find').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.autocomplete('auto/data.php?mode='+ $this.attr('id')  + '', {    
        width: 220,
        mzx: 5,
        selectFirst: false,      
        mustMatch:true,
        formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {return  value.split("|")[0];}
    });
});
```

`$('.Find').attr('id')` will always return the id of the first `.Find` in the page. So you can't use it like this.

Answer (score 1):

`$('.Find')` return an array of all DOM elements (wrapped in jquery) that got a 'Find' class.

You can access each element with [] operator - like `$('.Find')[0]`, or iterate trough the array with `for` lop. To get the id of the element use the id property.

To sum up - `$('.Find')[0].id` - id of the first element

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if i get what you want but i suppose you want to autocomplete all inputs with data from different urls based on the of the input, if so you can do this:

```
$('.Find').each(function(){
  $(this).autocomplete('auto/data.php?mode='+ $(this).attr('id')  +'', {    
                width: 220,
                max: 5,
                selectFirst: false,      
                mustMatch:true,
                formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {return  value.split("|")[0];}
  });
})
```

to get the id, in the each just do:

```
$(this).attr('id') or $(this).prop('id')
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to have a dynamic data source you need to set a `function()` as your source.

Also, the `this` attribute **does not return the actual DOM element**, rather than a more rich object that (of course) contains the actual elemet.

So, to achieve what you want you can try the following:

```
$('.Find').autocomplete({    
    source: function(request, response) {
        var id = this.element[0].id;
        var url = 'auto/data.php?mode='+ id;
        jQuery.getJSON(url, response).error(function () { /* handle JSON error */ }); 
    },
    width: 220,
    max: 5,
    selectFirst: false,      
    mustMatch:true,
    formatItem: function(data, i, n, value) {return  value.split("|")[0];}
});
```